# Show that $x-\alpha f(x)\to\pm\infty$ as $x\to\pm\infty$ if $\operatorname{sgn}(\alpha)\alpha f'\le c$ for some $c>0$

Tags: limits, asymptotics

Let $\alpha\in\mathbb R$, $c>0$, $f\in C^1(\mathbb R)$ with $$f'\left.\begin{cases}\le c&\text{, if }\alpha\ge0\\\ge-c&\text{, if }\alpha\le0\end{cases}\right\}\tag1$$ and $$g(x):=x-\alpha f(x)\;\;\;\text{for }x\in\mathbb R.$$

> How can we show that $g(x)\to\pm\infty$ as $x\to\pm\infty$?

While this should be easy, I don't know how we need to argue. Since the first term $x$ in the definition of $g(x)$ trivially goes to $\pm\infty$ as $x\to\pm\infty$, the reasoning should be that the second term cannot grow as fast and this should somehow follow from $(1)$ ...

Comment: This seems to be wrong. In the case $\alpha > 0$ you can choose $f(x) = x/\alpha$, which satisfies the condition with $c = 1/\alpha > 0$. But $g(x) = 0$ is constant.

Comment: Probably should be $c=1$ but yeah that gives a counterexample.

Comment: The condition $\alpha f'\le\operatorname{sgn}(\alpha)c$ in the title is not the same as the condition in the question body, which is $\operatorname{sgn}(\alpha)f'(x) \le c$.

Comment: @MartinR Oh, sorry, the title was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conclusions holds if and only if $|\alpha| c < 1$.

I'll demonstrate this for the case $\alpha > 0$, the case $\alpha < 0$ works similarly, and in the case $\alpha = 0$ we have $g(x)= x$ so that the conclusion holds trivially.

If $\alpha > 0$ and $\alpha c \ge 1$ then $f(x) = x/\alpha$ with $f'(x) = 1/\alpha  \le c$ and $g(x) = 0$ is a counterexample.

If $\alpha > 0$ and $\alpha c < 1$ then $f'(x) \le c$ implies
$$
 f(x) \le f(0) + cx \implies 
g(x) \ge -\alpha f(0) + \underbrace{(1-\alpha c)}_{> 0} \underbrace{(x)}_{> 0}
$$
for $ x > 0$, and
$$
 f(x) \ge f(0) + cx \implies 
g(x) \le -\alpha f(0) + \underbrace{(1-\alpha c)}_{> 0} \underbrace{(x)}_{< 0}
$$
for $x < 0$. It follows that
$$
 \lim_{x\to +\infty} g(x) = +\infty \, ,\,  
\lim_{x\to -\infty} g(x) = -\infty \, .
$$

Comment: This refers to the condition on $f'$ as described in the question body. As Andre made me aware, the condition is different in the question title.

Comment: Might be trivial, but how do you obtain $f(x)\le f(0)+cx$? From the mean value theorem I obtain $f(x)-f(0)\le\frac cx$ instead.

Comment: No, the mean value theorem gives $f(x)-f(0)=(x-0)f'(\xi)\le xc $.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. Made a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

This follows from a simple analysis: for instance, if $\alpha > 0$, you know that $f'$ is upper bounded (by a positive constant $c$), so $g(x) \geq x - \alpha c \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$. The analysis for the other case (i.e., $\alpha < 0$) is completely similar.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm sorry, but there was a typo in the question. It shouldn't be $f'$, but $f$ in the definition of $g$. Otherwise the result would be really trivially as you stated.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment by Martin R mentions, it doesn't hold. You need some additional criteria.

Also I'm using the condition you mention in the title which is $$\alpha f'(x) \le sgn(\alpha)c $$ which is different from what you say in $(1)$.

If we additionally have that $sgn(\alpha)c <1$, then $1 - \alpha f'(x) = 1 - sgn(\alpha)c + sgn(\alpha)c - \alpha f'(x) \ge 1 - sgn(\alpha)c >0$

Then by the Mean Value Theorem, $g(x) -g(0) = x g'(b) $ for some $b$ between $0$ and $x$.
\begin{align}
&g(x) -g(0) = x g'(b) = x(1 - \alpha f'(b))\\
\implies &g(x) = -\alpha f(0) + x(1 - \alpha f'(b)) \\
\end{align}

If $x > 0$, then
$$g(x) = -\alpha f(0) + x(1 - \alpha f'(b)) > -\alpha f(0) + x(1 - sgn(\alpha)c) $$
and we can say that $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x)  = \infty $.

If $x <0$, we have
$$g(x) = -\alpha f(0) + x(1 - \alpha f'(b)) < -\alpha f(0) + x(1 - sgn(\alpha)c) $$
and $\lim_{x \to -\infty} g(x) = -\infty$

Comment: I was using the condition OP mentioned in the title which is different from what they mentioned as $(1)$ in the post.